# Is it possible to save an MVC Razor view into an actual html file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorgenerator

We are building an MVC app that creates physical HTML pages.
The app currently creates the pages dynamically using the normal MVC/Razor approach.

Rather than re-creating the output programatically to a file, is there anyway to grab the result built by razor and save it to a file?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can render the view to string, then save the string in a file ...

```
public string RenderViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext, viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View, ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I just did not get a chance to test this until now. Seems to be working well. Thanks so much!