# Convert objects to an html file in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to convert objects into an html file that resides in a folder on server.  The current code creates objects and adds input from the user into the objects.

```
var loanInfo = new LoanInformation();
            loanInfo.Purpose = "Refinance";
            loanInfo.RefinanceReason = model.RefinanceDetails.RefiReason;
            loanInfo.CurrentLender = model.RefinanceDetails.CurrentLender;
            loanInfo.Year = model.RefinanceDetails.VehicleYear;
            loanInfo.Make = model.RefinanceDetails.VehicleMake;
            loanInfo.Model = model.RefinanceDetails.VehicleModel;
            loanInfo.Vin = model.RefinanceDetails.Vin;
            loanInfo.DesiredAmount = model.RefinanceDetails.DesiredLoanAmt;
            loanInfo.DesiredPayment = model.RefinanceDetails.DesiredLoanPayment;
            loanInfo.DesiredTerm = model.RefinanceDetails.DesiredTerm;
            loanInfo.Mileage = model.RefinanceDetails.VehicleMileage;
```

Then from there it is bundled in this code

```
var id = _Interface.CreateLoanApplication(model.LoanType, primaryApplicant, jointApplicant,
                primaryEmployment, jointEmployment, loanInfo, qieNotes);
```

I need to take the id variable and generate an HTML file with it.  It currently is sent off to a service, but I am stuck as to how to stick it into an html file on server.

Comment: What do you mean by `stick it into an html file on server`? Why do you need a bunch of html files with this data on the server?

Comment: Thats the direction given.  I mean all the inputs from the user displayed into an html file when they submit this portion of the controller

Comment: Create a view that will represent this data and pass the model to that view to be rendered

Comment: They are looking for files they can download out of the server folder. not on the front end.  Can also send them to xml

Comment: You can google for writing razor view into string, which you can then convert into bytes and return to users as a file using `FileResult`

Comment: Vsevolod's idea is still good. You can user a razor template to format your output and save a render of it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418176/is-it-possible-to-save-an-mvc-razor-view-into-an-actual-html-file