# Render html files from ASP.NET Razor cshtml files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a web app built with ASP.NET 4.6.1 and uses the Razor view engine. Is it possible to execute a command that will render *all* my template files (.cshtml files) to static HTML?

I need static HTML files for certain steps in my build process and I can't think of how to render *all* my view files into html.

Comment: There is this answer to do it on-demand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22418176/is-it-possible-to-save-an-mvc-razor-view-into-an-actual-html-file. I don't see how this is possible for a static build process since the templates may contain dynamic data. There is also this similar answer with additional links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378829/is-there-an-example-on-using-razor-to-generate-a-static-html-page?rq=1.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of something like what you are talking about, but my idea was a way to generate JS files (for building PhoneGap apps, for instance).  The [project was on BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/bmains/mvctemplating).  The controller/view can generate the JS files necessary for executing the app, which was done by going to a URL to render the content, which you can [view in the demo app](https://bitbucket.org/bmains/mvctemplating/src/262ccb41645fe1f218d6a5b7b1a796b56f57aee8/MVCTemplating.Demo/Controllers/TestController.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).  Any controller in the app marked with a special attribute gets rendered out to a target folder.

I was hoping to invest more into it but didn't get too far.  However this was pretty easy to setup so I hope it can give you a starting point.  At worse, you can create a process that spawns a browser to target this URL...  At best, there is probably a better way to internalize the components to run "out of band."

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if exist a easy solution for that. But if you really need it through the build process I suggest to create a consoleApp and call it from the build.For the console you can use the [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) it compile/parse the razor for you.